# Flipped normals after loading in my raytracer

Tags: c++, graphics, raytracing, objloader

I'm working on a path/ray tracer in C++. But some objects have flipped normals after loading. Where this behaviour comes from or how to fix it?

[image: img]

[GitHub page](https://github.com/iweinbau/Ray-Tracing/tree/dev). I thought it was an issue with the normals behind the surface but the normals are flipped in some cases. Loading the model:

```
//OBJ Loader object.
bool OBJLoader::loadMesh (std::string filePath){
    // If the file is not an .obj file return false
    if (filePath.substr(filePath.size() - 4, 4) != ".obj"){
        std::cout << "No .obj file found at given file location: "<<filePath << std::endl;

    }
    //Open file stream
    std::ifstream file(filePath);

    //check if file is open.
    if (!file.is_open()){
        std::cout << "File was not opened!" << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    //Do file loading.
    std::cout << "Parsing obj-file: "<<filePath << std::endl;

    //constuct mesh data.
    bool smoothShading = false;
    std::string obj_name;
    std::vector<Vertex> vertices;
    std::vector<Vect3> Positions;
    std::vector<Vect3> Normals;
    std::vector<Vect2> UVs;

    std::vector<unsigned int> V_indices;

    //the current line
    std::string currentLine;
    //loop over each line and parse the needed data.
    while(std::getline(file, currentLine)){

        //for now we just print the line
        //std::cout << currentLine << std::endl;

        if(algorithm::startsWith(currentLine, "s ")){
            std::vector<std::string> line_split = algorithm::split(currentLine,' ');
            if( line_split[1] == std::string("off")){
                smoothShading = false;
            }else if(line_split[1] == std::string("1")){
                //enalbe smooth shading;
                smoothShading = true;
            }
        }

        //check if the line starts with v -> vertex.
        if(algorithm::startsWith(currentLine, "o ")){
            //construct new vertex position.
            std::vector<std::string> line_split = algorithm::split(currentLine,' ');

            obj_name = line_split[1];
        }

        //check if the line starts with v -> vertex.
        if(algorithm::startsWith(currentLine, "v ")){
            //construct new vertex position.
            std::vector<std::string> line_split = algorithm::split(currentLine,' ');

            float x = std::stof(line_split[1]);
            float y = std::stof(line_split[2]);
            float z = std::stof(line_split[3]);
            Vect3 pos = Vect3(x,y,z);
            Positions.push_back(pos);
        }

        //check if the line starts with vt -> vertex uv.
        if(algorithm::startsWith(currentLine, "vt ")){
            //construct new vertex uv.
            std::vector<std::string> line_split = algorithm::split(currentLine,' ');

            float u = std::stof(line_split[1]);
            float v = std::stof(line_split[2]);
            Vect2 uv = Vect2(u,v);
            UVs.push_back(uv);
        }

        //check if the line starts with vn -> vertex normals.
        if(algorithm::startsWith(currentLine, "vn ")){
            //construct new vertex normal.
            std::vector<std::string> line_split = algorithm::split(currentLine,' ');

            float x = std::stof(line_split[1]);
            float y = std::stof(line_split[2]);
            float z = std::stof(line_split[3]);
            Vect3 normal = Vect3(x,y,z);
            Normals.push_back(normal);
        }

        //check if the line starts with f -> constuct faces.
        if(algorithm::startsWith(currentLine, "f ")){
            //construct new vertex position.

            std::vector<std::string> line_split = algorithm::split(currentLine,' ');

            //@NOTE: this only works when mesh is already triangulated.
            //Parse all vertices.
            std::vector<std::string> vertex1 = algorithm::split(line_split[1],'/');
            std::vector<std::string> vertex2 = algorithm::split(line_split[2],'/');
            std::vector<std::string> vertex3 = algorithm::split(line_split[3],'/');

            if(vertex1.size() <= 1){
                //VERTEX 1
                Vect3 position = Positions[std::stoi(vertex1[0])-1];
                Vertex v1(position);
                vertices.push_back(v1);

                //VERTEX 2
                position = Positions[std::stoi(vertex2[0])-1];
                Vertex v2(position);
                vertices.push_back(v2);

                //VERTEX 3
                position = Positions[std::stoi(vertex3[0])-1];
                Vertex v3(position);
                vertices.push_back(v3);

                //Add to Indices array.
                //calculate the index number
                //The 3 comes from 3 vertices per face.
                unsigned int index = vertices.size() - 3;
                V_indices.push_back(index);
                V_indices.push_back(index+1);
                V_indices.push_back(index+2);
            }

            //check if T exist.
            else if(vertex1[1] == ""){
                //NO Uv
                //V -> index in the positions array.
                //N -> index in the normals array.

                //VERTEX 1
                Vect3 position = Positions[std::stoi(vertex1[0])-1];
                Vect3 normal = Normals[std::stoi(vertex1[2])-1];

                Vertex v1(position,normal);
                vertices.push_back(v1);

                //VERTEX 2
                position = Positions[std::stoi(vertex2[0])-1];
                normal = Normals[std::stoi(vertex2[2])-1];

                Vertex v2(position,normal);
                vertices.push_back(v2);

                //VERTEX 3
                position = Positions[std::stoi(vertex3[0])-1];
                normal = Normals[std::stoi(vertex3[2])-1];

                Vertex v3(position,normal);
                vertices.push_back(v3);

                //Add to Indices array.
                //calculate the index number
                //The 3 comes from 3 vertices per face.
                unsigned int index = vertices.size() - 3;
                V_indices.push_back(index);
                V_indices.push_back(index+1);
                V_indices.push_back(index+2);

            }else if (vertex1[1] != ""){
                //We have UV
                //V -> index in the positions array.
                //T -> index of UV
                //N -> index in the normals array.

                //VERTEX 1
                Vect3 position = Positions[std::stoi(vertex1[0])-1];
                Vect2 uv = UVs[std::stoi(vertex1[1])-1];
                Vect3 normal = Normals[std::stoi(vertex1[2])-1];

                Vertex v1(position,normal,uv);
                vertices.push_back(v1);

                //VERTEX 2
                position = Positions[std::stoi(vertex2[0])-1];
                uv = UVs[std::stoi(vertex2[1])-1];
                normal = Normals[std::stoi(vertex2[2])-1];

                Vertex v2(position,normal,uv);
                vertices.push_back(v2);

                //VERTEX 3
                position = Positions[std::stoi(vertex3[0])-1];
                uv = UVs[std::stoi(vertex3[1])-1];
                normal = Normals[std::stoi(vertex3[2])-1];

                Vertex v3(position,normal,uv);
                vertices.push_back(v3);

                //Add to Indices array.
                //calculate the index number
                //The 3 comes from 3 vertices per face.
                unsigned int index = vertices.size() - 3;
                V_indices.push_back(index);
                V_indices.push_back(index+1);
                V_indices.push_back(index+2);
            }

            //We can check here in which format. V/T/N, V//N, V//, ...
            //For now we ignore this and use V//N.
        }
    }

    //close stream
    file.close();

    Positions.clear();
    Normals.clear();
    UVs.clear();

    //reorder the arrays so the coresponding index match the position,uv and normal.
    for (Vertex v: vertices) {
        Positions.push_back(v.getPosition());
        Normals.push_back(v.getNormal());
        UVs.push_back(v.getUV());
    }

    //Load mesh data.
    _mesh = Mesh(smoothShading,obj_name, Positions, Normals, UVs, V_indices);

    //return true, succes.
    return true;
```

The model is inserted in a grid for faster intersection tests:

```
for(int i= 0;i<mesh._indices.size();i=i+3){
    Triangle* tri;
    if(mesh.smoothShading){
        tri = new SmoothTriangle(Point3(mesh._positions[mesh._indices[i]]),
                                 Point3(mesh._positions[mesh._indices[i+1]]),
                                 Point3(mesh._positions[mesh._indices[i+2]]),
                                 Normal(mesh._normals[mesh._indices[i]]),
                                 Normal(mesh._normals[mesh._indices[i+1]]),
                                 Normal(mesh._normals[mesh._indices[i+2]]),material);
    }else{
        tri = new Triangle(Point3(mesh._positions[mesh._indices[i]]),
                           Point3(mesh._positions[mesh._indices[i+1]]),Point3(mesh._positions[mesh._indices[i+2]]),Normal(mesh._normals[mesh._indices[i]]),material);
    }

    add_object(tri);
}
constructCells();
```

Interpolating normals:

```cpp
Normal SmoothTriangle::calculate_normal(double gamma, double beta){
    return (Normal((1 - beta - gamma) * n0 + beta * n1 + gamma * n2)).normalize();
}
```

Comment: I Fixed the issue. It was not in my OBJ loader. the model was exported from blender and when exporting it applied all modifiers, but the Solidify caused some back faces to clip with the front faces, after exporting to .obj file. After removing this modifier everything was back to "normal" (Just a funny pun to finish this answer)

Comment: @theVortr3x Do not include solution to question please (post a separate answer instead).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be nothing wrong in your code I assume that the obj is corrupted as some obj models have flipped normals ...

**Wavefront obj** format does not specify the normal direction at all I saw even models without consistency so some normals points out others in. You can not even be sure the faces have single **winding rule**. So its safer to use **bidirectional normals** (you know using

```
|dot(normal,light)|
```

instead of

```
dot(normal,light)
```

and **no face culling** or recompute the normals and even winding rule on your own after load.

The bidirectional normals/lighting are sometimes set by different material settings for each side of face `FRONT` and `BACK` or `FRONT_AND_BACK` or `DOUBLE_SIDED` etc or its configuration... just look in your gfx API for such stuff. To turn off the face culling look for things like `CULL_FACE`